# in Javascript API; handling Arrays returned in FQL Queries

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to access the Hometown_Location attribute on the user table. It is listed as an array and is returned in the response object but I dont know who to access the data in the object. does anyone have any example of how to access non-string attributes in an FQL query?

Comment: It is returned to you inside the JSON response as an object – so you access it’s properties like with any other object, via `object.propertyname`

Answer (score 1):

A sample response is:

```
{
   "id": "1234567890",
   "name": "Brandon Fisch",
   "location": {
      "id": "110970792260960",
      "name": "Los Angeles, California"
   }
}
```

To access the location name you would use:

```
response.location.name
```